# Error populating dropdown using jquery ajax call returning more than 400 records

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I intent to populate drop down box using AJAX Call. If number of records returned by web method is less than 400 then success method is called & dropdown is populated. But if no of records returned by web methods is more then 400> then i get an error [object Object] in error function

It sounds strange but i am not able to figure out the issue.

If include Top 400 in stored procedure than there is no issue but when i remove Top syntax or increase it then dropdown is not populate & I receive an error.

Hence there is no issue with Webmethod or Ajax Call. Is number of records returned by webmethod is concern ?

[WebMethod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WeZa.jpg) [AJAX Call Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic5Kr.jpg)

I am calling function to populate in Document.Ready(function ())

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Please don't put code in pictures. Put them in actual code block.

Answer (score 0):

Identified issue. It was related to jsonSerialization maxJsonLength propery which needs to be increased in web config file. Hope it would help someone else. :)